# Fastlane finished with errors - Match - no error message

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

I updated fastlane to the newest version ( 2.162.0)

Now when I try to run fastlane buildApp, it errors out and hangs forever with the only output:

> fastlane finished with errors

**Terminal Output:**

```
% fastlane buildApp
[✔]  
[14:59:43]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[14:59:44]: ------------------------------
[14:59:44]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[14:59:44]: ------------------------------
[14:59:44]: Driving the lane 'ios buildApp' 
+------------------+--------------+
|          Lane Context           |
+------------------+--------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios          |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios          |
| LANE_NAME        | ios buildApp |
+------------------+--------------+

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[14:59:45]: fastlane finished with errors
```

However, if I run the match command directly into my terminal, it works fine without a problem.

```
fastlane match appstore --force=true --app_identifier=com.MyCompany.AppName
```

**Fastfile** (Stripped down to reproduce the problem)

```
default_platform(:ios)
platform :ios do
  lane :buildApp do
    match(force: "true", type:"appstore", app_identifier: "com.MyCompany.AppName")
  end
end
```

So my question is why does this work when typed directly in the console but no longer works via my Fastfile?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying different things, I finally ran:

```
sudo gem clean
```

And now it works as expected -_-

Putting this here in case it saves anyone else the frustration!

Comment: Hi Buddy, do you have idea about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185846/fastlane-finished-with-errors-shell-error-exit-status-of-command-python3