# fastlane finished with errors "Shell error" [!] Exit status of command 'python3 ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py'

Tags: python, ruby, android-studio, jenkins, fastlane

Hi i am using fastlane for update localization string files in the project, It was working perfectly on M1 but when I change to M1 Pro, fastelane giving this error.

```
[✔]  
[19:07:30]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[19:07:30]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[19:07:30]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[19:07:30]: 
[19:07:30]: $ bundle exec fastlane localized_copy_generation
[19:07:30]: 
[19:07:30]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane 
https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
/Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/digest-3.1.1/lib/digest.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Digest::REQUIRE_MUTEX

/Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/digest.rb:6: warning: previous definition of REQUIRE_MUTEX was here
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                            Used plugins                                             |
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Plugin                             | Version | Action                                               |
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-versioning_android | 0.1.1   | android_get_version_name, android_set_version_code,  |
|                                    |         | android_set_version_name, android_get_version_code   |
| fastlane-plugin-appcenter          | 2.1.0   | appcenter_fetch_version_number,                      |
|                                    |         | appcenter_fetch_devices,                             |
|                                    |         | appcenter_codepush_release_react, appcenter_upload   |
| fastlane-plugin-dynatrace          | 2.0.0   | dynatrace                                            |
| fastlane-plugin-teams              | 0.2.0   | teams                                                |
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+

[19:07:31]: ------------------------------
[19:07:31]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[19:07:31]: ------------------------------
[19:07:31]: Driving the lane 'android localized_copy_generation' 
[19:07:31]: -------------------------------------
[19:07:31]: --- Step: ensure_git_status_clean ---
[19:07:31]: -------------------------------------
[19:07:31]: $ git status --porcelain
[19:07:31]: Git status is clean, all good! 
[19:07:31]: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[19:07:31]: --- Step: python3 ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py ---
[19:07:31]: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[19:07:31]: $ python3 ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py
[19:07:34]: ▸ Traceback (most recent call last):
[19:07:34]: ▸ File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 303, in <module>
[19:07:34]: ▸ content = prepare_to_parse()
[19:07:34]: ▸ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[19:07:34]: ▸ File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 274, in prepare_to_parse
[19:07:34]: ▸ content = main()
[19:07:34]: ▸ ^^^^^^

[19:07:34]: ▸ File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 77, in main

[19:07:34]: ▸ content = content.append(df, ignore_index=True)

[19:07:34]: ▸ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

[19:07:34]: ▸ File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas
/core/generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__

[19:07:34]: ▸ return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

[19:07:34]: ▸ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

[19:07:34]: ▸ AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                          Lane Context                           |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM            | android                           |
| PLATFORM_NAME               | android                           |
| LANE_NAME                   | android localized_copy_generation |
| GIT_REPO_WAS_CLEAN_ON_START | true                              |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+

[19:07:34]: Exit status of command 'python3 ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py' was 1 instead of 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 303, in <module>
    content = prepare_to_parse()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 274, in prepare_to_parse
    content = main()
              ^^^^^^

  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 77, in main
    content = content.append(df, ignore_index=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?


+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|                              fastlane summary                              |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                                | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                                      | 0           |
| 2    | ensure_git_status_clean                               | 0           |
|    | python3                                               | 2           |
|      | ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopy |             |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+

[19:07:34]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

/Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:153:in `shell_error!': [!] Exit status of command 'python3 ../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py' was 1 instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneShellError)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 303, in <module>
    content = prepare_to_parse()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 274, in prepare_to_parse
    content = main()
              ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dalvindersandhu/AirCanada/aircanadamobileandroid/fastlane/../buildScripts/localizedCopyGeneration/LocalizedCopyGeneration.py", line 77, in main
    content = content.append(df, ignore_index=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?

        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:80:in `sh_control_output'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:16:in `sh_no_action'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:223:in `block in sh'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:222:in `sh'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:216:in `sh'
        from Fastfile:224:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:354:in `run'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
        from /Users/dalvindersandhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

Getting this error
[image]

I used these command to install component

**install rvm:**

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s head
```

**Install Ruby:**

```
rvm install 2.5
```

**Install Bundler:**

```
gem install bundler
```

**Install project dependencies (Fastlane):**

```
bundle install
```

**Install Python3:**

```
brew install python3
```

**Install copy script dependencies:**

```
pip3 install google-api-python-client

pip3 install oauth2client

pip3 install pandas
```

**Run copy script**
fastlane localized_copy_generation

Please help if anyone faced same problem

system info:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | 13.3.1 |
| Ruby | 2.6.10 |
| Bundler? | true |
| Git | git version 2.33.0 |
| Installation Source | ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.10/bin/fastlane |
| Host | macOS 13.3.1 (22E261) |
| Ruby Lib Dir | ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.10/lib |
| OpenSSL Version | OpenSSL 1.1.1t 7 Feb 2023 |
| Is contained | false |
| Is homebrew | false |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false |
| Xcode Path | /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ |
| Xcode Version |  |

Comment: Please copy/paste the error as text instead of a screenshot. Also use proper formatting for code, including bash commands.